# Should there be a abstraction layer between database and model?

Tags: model-view-controller, orm, model, repository-pattern

What I see a lot is that people use a Object Relational Mapper (ORM) for doing SQL stuff when working in a MVC environment. But if i really have complex queries I would like to write this whole query myself. What is the best practice for this kind of situation?

1. Having a Abstraction Layer between your model and the database with the complex queries
2. Still using the model with creating specific methodes that handle the queries

Or is there any other way that might be better? please tell me :)

Comment: You want to keep queries out of your controllers for sure. I use DoctrinePHP and it has "Repositories" where I can store custom code to build complex queries, which is kind of the layer you're asking about. If your ORM doesn't have one, either store in your models, or create custom classes of your own separately.

Comment: You should definitely provide an abstraction between your domain and your datasources. In MVC, the "domain model" includes datasources as well, so it's important to make the distinction between "models" and "model". The former is merely your entities, the latter is the general architectural concept in the MVC sense.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software architecture and not a specific programming problem. If you want more information, you should take a look at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). Read trough the posts first though, I am certain you'll find a lot of excellent material on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  Specifically, the question would be...

"If I put data access logic in my model, what will that mean when I need to change something?"

Any time you need to change business logic, you're also changing the objects which maintain data access logic.  So the data access logic also needs to be re-tested.  Conversely, any time you need to change data access logic, you're also changing the objects which maintain business logic.  So the business logic also needs to be re-tested.

As the logic expands, this becomes more difficult very quickly.

The idea behind the Single Responsibility Principle is to separate the dependencies of different roles which can enact changes to the application.  (Keep in mind that "roles" doesn't map 1-to-1 with "people."  One person may have multiple roles, but it's still important to separate those roles.)  It's a matter of simpler support.  If you want to make a change to a database query (say, for performance reasons) which shouldn't have any visible affect on anything else in the system, then there's no reason to be changing objects which contain business logic.

Answer (score 1):

> `1.` Having a Abstraction Layer between your model and the database with the complex queries

Yes, you should have a persistence abstraction that sits between storage (database or any other data source) and you business logic. Your business logic should not depend on "where", "how" and even "if" the data is actually stored.

Basically, your code should (at least - try to) adhere to [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29), but as @david already pointed out: you are already violating the first on on that list.

Also, you should consider using a [service layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) which would be responsible for dealing with interaction between implementation of domain model and your persistence abstraction (doesn't matter whether you are using custom written [data mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) or some 3rd party ORM).

In the article (more like excerpt, actually) the "MVC model" is actually all three concentric circles together. [Domain model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model) is not code. It actually is trm that describs the accumulated knowledge about the project. Most of domain model gets turned into pieces of code. Those pieces are referred to as [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject).

> `2.` Still using the model with creating specific methodes that handle the queries

This would imply implementation of [active record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html). It is useful, but **mostly misused** pattern, for cases when your objects have no (or almost none) business logic. Basically - you should use active record **only** if all you need are glorified setter an getters, that talk to database.

Active record pattern is a very good choice when you need to quickly prototype something, but it **should not be used**, when you are attempting to implement fully realized model layer.

Comment: My mind must've been elsewhere, it had nothing to do with it. I've removed it to prevent misconceptions. One small remark though: you suggest a service layer between domain model and persistence; isn't a service layer meant between to be used between controllers and domain model instead?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: I really hope that I did not. What I tried to say is that services should be handling the interaction between domain objects and persistence abstraction (either mappers directly or UoW's). Services would contain lines like `userMapper.save(user);`, where they indicate the wiring between domain and persistence. They also essentially would act as "interfaces" through which presentation layer (controllers, views, presentation objects and others) interact with model layer ... been typing as fast as could, maybe I just expressed myself clumsily.

Comment: Got it, I think it's just a matter of terminology. As far as I know a service layer is specifically used to name the interface between the controllers and the domain. The data source layer provides the interface between the domain and the persistence. They're both service layers in the general sense of the word, but a service layer is particularly used to indicate the interface between controllers and domain model.

Comment: Well. This **is** kinda the same. I think the main difference is that IMHO the domain model itself. should not be aware of fact that it is persisted somewhere. And yes. Terminology is the proverbial clusterfu*k in DDD and application architecture as whole, especially since the *"arrival of glorious RoR"*.

Answer (score 0):

ORM's in general do not specifically have any drawbacks versus using direct SQL to fetch data from the database. ORM's as the name implies help in keeping your Relational model (designed using your SQL DDL's or using JPA annotations) and OO model in sync and help them integrate well together.

When using a ORM, you can write your queries in JPQL which is Object oriented SQL. So instead of writing queries that manipulate tables, you are writing queries that manipulate objects. You use the relationships between these objects to get your desired result. Now I understand that sometimes its easier to just write Native SQL, so the JPA specification allows you to run native sql! This just returns you list of "Generic Objects" which you can organize any way you like. When you choose to go this route and actually pick a JPA provider, like Hibernate, these providers have extended functionalities. So if you do have complex relationships you can use libraries like Hibernate Criteria Builder to help you create queries for those complex relationships.

So, if building a large MVC application, it would generally be a good idea to have this abstraction layer in the middle - handling all these relationships. It makes it easier on you the developer to just look at the big picture and the business side of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Imho, no. I think, even the ORM layer adds often more complexity as needed. The databases have very good and sophisticated mechanisms for high-level data manipulation. Triggers, views, constraints, complex keying-indexing, (sub)transactions, stored procedures, and procedural extensions of the query language were normally much more as enough for everything.

The ORMs can't give, because of their structural barriers, a real interface to this feature set.

And the common practice is that the applications use practically only a nosql record service from all of this, and implement in an unneeded "middleware" which were the mission of the database.

Which I see really interesting, if the feature set of the databases got some OO-like interface (see "sql abstract types"), and the client-side logic went in the application (see "REST"). This practically eliminated the need of the middle layer.